# WireGuard VPN: wg0.conf does not exist

Tags: linux, vpn, wireguard

I am trying to setup VPN on my server with help of WireGuard. I am following this tutorial https://upcloud.com/resources/tutorials/get-started-wireguard-vpn

**ERROR**

```
systemctl status wg-quick@wg0
× wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-17 08:31:15 UTC; 15h ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
   Main PID: 5700 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 5ms

Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru wg-quick[5700]: wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 08:31:15 v1567418.hosted-by-vdsina.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

**My actions:**

Uncommented line in file sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Applied the change below

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Configured /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 58723
PrivateKey = XXXXX


PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;ip6tables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;ip6tables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;


[Peer]
# Client Name: Unnamed
PublicKey = MY__PUB_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128
```

Then I am starting WG

```
> wg-quick up wg0
wg-quick: `wg0' already exists
```

Then I am enabling WG to start automatically

```
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

If it shows `wg-quick: wg0' already exists`, just run

```bash
sudo wg-quick down wg0
```

and then:

```bash
sudo wg-quick up wg0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type
`sudo wg` or `sudo wg-quick show` to view your current wireguard connection.

It says that `wg-quick: wg0' already exists`  so you have to disable it and reenable it
`wg-quick down wg0` ,`wg-quick up wg0`

Or if you want to chain it together `sudo wg-quick down wg0; wg-quick up wg0`